# How to parse JSON array of integers

Tags: go

I have a response of: `[18094823,18082017,18088099,18078184,18086418]` that's a *net/http.Response.

How do I parse this? There is clear documentation on how to use a JSON struct to Decode a stream of JSON objects but not a simple array of numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You decode it just like any other structure JSON object. You just have to define a valid structure which in this case is simply array of integers. Of course before you can do that you need to get response bytes using ioutil.ReadAll

```
package main

import "encoding/json"
import "fmt"

var data string = "[18094823,18082017,18088099,18078184,18086418]"
func main() {
    fmt.Print(data)
    res := make([]int, 0)
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &res)
    fmt.Println(res)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/h5LAOgYnROq

Comment: Since the data in my case is from an http request I get:

cannot convert resp.Body (type io.ReadCloser) to type []byte

Do you know what I'd need to change to make your answer fit my situation? I've accepted your answer as correct. Thanks for the help.

Comment: body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

This does the job of converting io.ReadCloser to []bytes